# javascript inheritance with protected variables

Tags: javascript, oop

Is it possible in javascript to have a variable that is not able to access out side the class's functions, but is able to be accessed by classes that inherit it? I.E:

```
class1 has protected var x = 4;

class2 inherits class1;

class2.prototype.getVar = function(){return /* parent, uber, super, whatever */ this.x;};

var cl2 = new class2();

console.log(cl2.x) // undefined
console.log(cl2.getVar()) // 4
```

Comment: Not directly; that's not how JavaScript is designed.

Comment: There's really no need for it. private and protected variables are designed only to keep programmers from harming themselves.

Comment: "there's really no need for it."  Yes there is and you stated it - to keep programmers from harming themselves!

Comment: [Proclass](https://github.com/bfrohs/Proclass) may be of some help. - Disclosure: I wrote it, so I'm biased ;) - You have to change the syntax a bit, but it's fairly usable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Prototypal inheritance is limited to properties of objects.

Variables within the constructor are only available to other code in that variable scope.

You could probably come up with something like...

```
function cls1() {
    var a = 'foo';
    this.some_func = function() {
        alert(a);
    };
}

function cls2() {
    cls1.apply(this, arguments);
    var cls1_func = this.some_func;

    var b = 'bar'

    this.some_func = function() {
        cls1_func.apply(this, arguments);
        alert(b);
    };
}

var x = new cls2;

x.some_func();  // alert "foo"  alert "bar"
```

---

Or to make it more specific to your pseudo code...

```
function class1() {
    var x = 4;
    this.getVar = function() {
        return x;
    };
}

function class2() {

    class1.apply(this, arguments);

    var cls1_get_var = this.getVar;

    this.getVar = function() {
        return cls1_get_var.apply(this, arguments);
    };
}

class2.prototype = Object.create( class1.prototype );

var cl2 = new class2;

console.log(cl2.x) // undefined
console.log(cl2.getVar()) // 4
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to use a closure to achieve what your trying to do. Something like this:

```
            Class1 = function() {
                var x = 4;
                return {
                    getVar: function() {
                        return x;
                    }
                }
            } ();// executes the function immediately and returns an
                //an object with one method - getVar. Through closure this method
                //still has access to the variable x


            Class2 = function() { };// define a constructor function
            Class2.prototype = Class1;//have it inherit from Class1

            Cl2 = new Class2();//instantiate a new instance of Class2
            console.log(Cl2.x);//this is undefined
            console.log(Cl2.getVar());//this outputs 4
```

This is one of the neat things about javascript in that you can achieve the same things in javascript as you would in a class based language without all the extra key words. Douglas Crockford (always good to consult about javascript) explains prototypal inheritance  [here](http://javascript.crockford.com/prototypal.html)

**Edit:**

Just had a second look at your question.If you want newly created methods in your class to access the variable in the base class then you would have to call the getVar method within your own method.Like such:

```
              Class2 = function() {
                    this.getVar2 = function() {
                        return this.getVar();
                    }
                };


                   console.log(Cl2.getVar2()) //outputs 4
```